# Do I have to add an ingredient to compensate for removing about 100g of sugar from zucchini bread?

Tags: vegan, gluten-free, quickbread, sweeteners

I want to adapt a zucchini-bread recipe so that it's **not at all sweet** (I want to toast slices and top them with savory stuff). The recipe is vegan and gluten-free, so I can't use a well-beaten egg to help compensate for the omitted sweeteners -- 50g sugar and 56g of maple syrup. To help you devise a reply: The recipe also calls for 2 cups (about 270g) of oat flour, about 70g of coconut oil, 1.5 flax eggs (11g ground flax + 33g [ml] water), and 1 cup of grated zucchini (not sure how much that would weigh).

If my budget weren't so tight, I'd add a little almond flour. I assume that I could add about 50g of gluten-free flour and another tsp of coconut oil, but I'm not sure whether that would work. (I don't want to add more oat flour bc I think, based on trying a lot of oat-flour recipes, that would create a gummy loaf.) Any ideas? Thank you v much.

Comment: find another recipe that doesn't have sugar. This is unlikely to work out properly as-is.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding sweetened or unsweetened applesauce to your liking. It should also help keep the loaf moist.

Comment: I appreciate your taking time to answer, but even unsweetened applesauce is sweet, so it won't work. As noted, my goal is to make a loaf that can be used with savory toppings.